# high linux server load

Tags: linux, high-load, iowait

I have a problem with high server load (load average from 10 to 100+) when there is a lot of web traffic. There are also noticable delays when reading/writing files.
Machine is a Apache web server. Web page is using PHP and is accessing/opening some small (max 30kB) files (config, blacklist, file from cache directory).

Im trying to trace the couse of this issue for couple of days now. This is what I found out:

- CPU load is below 10%
- load is coused by long disk response. `top` shows `%wa` parameter (iowait) at 20-100%
- iostat: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZzSuUvBV)
- after some testing it appears that the problem is one, specific fopen() function in my PHP script, accessing cache files
- if I delete the line with this specific fopen(), server load is going down fast, to 0.00-0.50 values, iowait is 0%

Some informations about server:

- xeon e3-1245v2, 32 gb ram, 2x 2TB SATA3 drives with software RAID 1 (mirroring), filesystem ext4 (with `dir-index` enabled and `noatime` in fstab)
- cache directory size is about 500GB

  - it has about 16-17 milion files, each 20-30KB
  - filenames are MD5 hashes
  - directory structure is (example): `cacheDir/d4/1d/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.dat`
  - so there is 256 directories in `cacheDir/` (1st level) and 256 2nd level directories (in each 1st level directory)
  - so, on average, there is about 200-300 files per 2nd level directory
- PHP is `fopen`'ing cache files with absolute paths
- disks were checked: no errors/warnings
- `e2fsck -Df` (optimize  directories  in  filesystem) result is [here](http://pasteboard.co/2MkeIx7b.png)
- after `e2fsck -Df` there was no difference in server load

I thought, that such cache directory organisation would be good for optimal disk performance. Apparently I was wrong..

What would you recomend to fix this high load/slow disk reponse issue?

Comment: Buy faster disks.  Look at alternate architectures.  Is implementing a cache within PHP really the right thing?  Why not setup a caching server specifically designed for caching.  Maybe use memcache instead of the filesystem.  Stop caching, do you really need to cache, are you sure you were not prematurely optimizing?

Comment: 600GB of memcache? Seriously?

Comment: This cache is a result of other program many months work (getting some online informations). If it wasnt cached, I would have to download it every time I run the script.

Comment: Note how that was the third item in a list?  Is your cache usage random, or could you simply put the most frequently used 10% in memory, and hit disk for the less common stuff?  My first suggestion still stands **buy faster storage**.  Do you really think you are going to sustain high I/O on a two SATA drives in a RAID1?

Comment: Cache usage is totally random, so memcache is not possible. The problem is that **one, specific** directory (cache directory). If I replace this `fopen` with 20 `fopen`s but accessing different files (not the ones in cache directory), then server load is normal. Accessing cache directory makes disks respond longer than accessing any other files...